# how does awk FIELDWIDTHS WORK

Tags: awk, gnu

I started learning awk programming few days back (Effective awk scripting).  At page 102 the author was explaining fieldwidths, but I don't understand how it works. Please could someone kindly explain to me, how fieldwidths works?

Comment: Well, it let you set fields based on their width (see [GNU doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html) instead of a [delimiter/separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html).

Comment: how will i be able to know the width of a field .?

Comment: To clarify: variable `FIELDWIDTHS` is a nonstandard _GNU_ `awk`-specific extension to the [POSIX awk spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **FIELDWIDTHS** A whitespace separated list of field widths.  When set,
>   gawk parses the input into fields of fixed width, instead of using the
>   value of the FS variable as the field separator.

I think an example is better to explain how does it work:

```
$ echo "aaabbbbcccccdddddd"|awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="3 4 5 6" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'    
aaa
bbbb
ccccc
dddddd
```

It is useful, when it is difficult to find a `FS` of the record, but the record has fixed length fields.