# Using awk to split a record into multiple fields

Tags: awk

I have a file with records which are not separated by any delimiter . A sample is shared below:

XXXXXYYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYYYZZZ

I have been given a DDL for the file such that field 1 lies in the  position 1-5, field 2 lies in the position 6-9 , field 3 lies in the position 10-12

How to use awk command to print the below output?

field1,field2,field3
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ

Comment: start with formatting your description, it's unreadable now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how does awk FIELDWIDTHS WORK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085137/how-does-awk-fieldwidths-work)

Comment: the field length can vary . This is just a sample. My file can have more than 50 columns field 1 position may 1-10 , field 2 may be 11-15 and son. Moreover I need the output along with header as shown .Pls help

Comment: If the fieldwidths vary within a file, how would you recognize the field change?

Comment: You have to derive the fieldwidths from the DDL? Can you show us the DDL file for the data file?

Answer (score 1):

IN GNU awk using `FIELDWIDTHS`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS="5 4 3"                 # here you state the field widths
    OFS=","                             # output field separator
    print "field1","field2","field3" }  # print header in BEGIN
{
    print $1,$2,$3 }                    # print 3 first fields, you could also:
' file                                  # {$1=$1; print} or even:
field1,field2,field3                    # {$1=$1}1
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
```

If you don't have GNU awk, use `f1=substr($0,1,5);f2=substr($0,6,4)...print f1,f2,f3`.

**Edit:**

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS=","
    print "field1","field2","field3" }
{
    f1=substr($0,1,5)
    f2=substr($0,6,4)
    f3=substr($0,10,3)
    print f1,f2,f3 }
' file
```

Latter as one-liner with `;`s inserted:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=","; print "field1","field2","field3"}{f1=substr($0,1,5); f2=substr($0,6,4); f3=substr($0,10,3); print f1,f2,f3}' file
```

The former as one-liner:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="5 4 3"; OFS=","; print "field1","field2","field3"}{print $1,$2,$3}' file
```

Comment: I Tried awk 'BEGIN {f1=substr($0,1,5);f2=substr($0,6,4);f3=substr($0,10,3) print "field1","field2","field3" } { print f1,f2,f3 }' file --- It didnot work @james

Comment: awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS="5 4 3" OFS="," print "field1","field2","field3" } { print $1,$2,$3 }' file`-- @james It didnot work . Says syntax error

Comment: Apparently you don't have GNU awk, gimme a sec, I'll edit the latter as full answer.

Comment: awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="5 4 3" 'OFS="," { print "field1","field2","field3" } { print $1,$2,$3 }' a.txt  --- This piece of syntax works but prints header for each record . Pls correct me @james

Comment: Well the first `{...}` block should be `BEGIN{...}`.

Comment: awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="5 4 3" 'OFS="," BEGIN{ print "field1","field2","field3" } { print $1,$2,$3 }' file-- gives syntax error.Pls help me @james

Comment: `FIELDWIDTHS` and `OFS` are defined before the first `'` like `-v OFS=...` or inside the `BEGIN` block. `BEGIN` block must be after the first `'`.

Comment: Can you kindly post here the exact syntax. I have tried but it shows syntax error only :(

Comment: Not sure if any space is causing issue. I have tried both of your solutions in a single line syntax. But throwing error-@james

Comment: Single line syntax as in one-liner?  Did you add `;`s between commands? See my edit on the bottom.

Comment: It is woking now...Thanks a lot @james

Comment: How to use FIXEDWIDTHS syntax in one-liner ? Please help @james

Comment: awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS="5 4 3"; OFS=","; print "field1","field2","field3"}{print $1,$2,$3}'  file  ----works fine .Thanks a lot @james

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '1i\field1,field2,field3' -e 's/[^,]/,&/6;s//,&/10' file
```

Comment: @user3439894 quite right. I didn't see the header. Amended

Answer (score 0):

without using `substr()`, here's a not-so-elegant `awk` way to get around it

```
echo 'XXXXXYYYYZZZ
      XXXXXYYYYZZZ
      XXXXXYYYYZZZ
      XXXXXYYYYZZZ
      XXXXXYYYYZZZ' |
```

> ```
>  mawk 'BEGIN {  OFS = ","
>           print (__ = "field")(++_), (__)(++_), (__)(++_)
>                   _ = (_ = (_ = ".")_)_
>                  __ = "&,"                
>        } sub("." _,__) + sub("," _,__)^_'
> ```

```
field1,field2,field3
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
XXXXX,YYYY,ZZZ
```