# AWK or SED Replace space between alphabets in a particular column

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have an infile as below:

infile:

```
INM00042170  28.2500   74.9167  290.0    CHURU                          2015 2019   2273 
INM00042182  28.5833   77.2000  211.0    NEW DELHI/SAFDARJUNG           1930 2019  67874
INXUAE05462  28.6300   77.2000  216.0    NEW DELHI                      1938 1942   2068
INXUAE05822  25.7700   87.5200   40.0    PURNEA                         1933 1933    179
INXUAE05832  31.0800   77.1800 2130.0    SHIMLA                         1926 1928    728
PKM00041640  31.5500   74.3333  214.0    LAHORE CITY                    1960 2019  22915
```

I want to replace the space between two words by an underscore in column 5 (example: NEW DELHI becomes NEW_DELHI). I want output as below.

outfile:

```
INM00042170  28.2500   74.9167  290.0    CHURU                          2015 2019   2273 
INM00042182  28.5833   77.2000  211.0    NEW_DELHI/SAFDARJUNG           1930 2019  67874
INXUAE05462  28.6300   77.2000  216.0    NEW_DELHI                      1938 1942   2068
INXUAE05822  25.7700   87.5200   40.0    PURNEA                         1933 1933    179
INXUAE05832  31.0800   77.1800 2130.0    SHIMLA                         1926 1928    728
PKM00041640  31.5500   74.3333  214.0    LAHORE_CITY                    1960 2019  22915
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: I tried a basic one but it is not working because it considers word after space as a next column. so when trying to print column 5 it only shows "NEW". I do not have much idea on it.

Comment: With GNU `awk`, you may try to use `FIELDWIDTHS`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085137/how-does-awk-fieldwidths-work

Comment: See https://ideone.com/EHbB44

Comment: What is the other whitespace? Spaces? Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# connect field 5 and 6 and remove those with numbers. 
# this returns a list of new names (with underscore) for 
# all cities that need to be replaced 
declare -a NEW_NAMES=$(cat infile | awk '{print $5 "_" $6}' | grep -vE "_[0-9]")

# iterating all new names
for NEW_NAME in ${NEW_NAMES[@]}; do
  OLD_NAME=$(echo $NEW_NAME | tr '_' ' ')
  # replace in file
  sed -i "s/${OLD_NAME}/${NEW_NAME}/g" infile
done
```